# Как сделать submit формы для авторизации в вконтакте

Tags: python, авторизация, вконтакте, python-3.x

Пытаюсь авторизоваться в вконтакте:

```
url_open = urllib.request.urlopen("http://vk.com/")
page_r = lxml.html.document_fromstring(url_open.read())
form = page_r.forms[0]
form.inputs['email'].value = 'мой_email'
form.inputs['pass'].value = 'мой_пароль'
```

Но на `response = form.submit()` или `response = form.submit_form()` получаю такую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#76>", line 1, in <module>
response = form.submit()
AttributeError: 'FormElement' object has no attribute 'submit'
```

Что я делаю не так и как еще можно нажать на кнопку "Войти"? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала есть проблема в том, что отправка формы производится через функцию `submit_form`, а не через методы `submit` или `submit_form`.

Вторая проблема состоит в том, что у реализации lxml под Python 3 есть [баг с кодировкой отправляемых значений](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/pull/122). Этой же проблеме посвящено [обсуждение на главном сайте](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151333/post-method-form-in-lxml-raises-typeerror-with-submit-form).

Самым простым, но непереносимым решением будет следующее:
Открыть файл `<путь-к-библиотекам-python3>/lxml/html/__init__.py`
Найти в нём функцию `open_http_urllib` и в её предпоследней строке заменить `data = urlencode(values)` на `data = urlencode(values).encode('utf-8')`
(т.е. повторить действия [pull-request](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/pull/122/files))

Более правильно будет завести свою функцию `open_http`:

```
def open_http(method, url, values):
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    from urllib.parse import urlencode

    data = urlencode(values).encode('utf-8')
    return urlopen(url, data)
```

Это упрощённая, работающая только с `POST`-запросами функция, которая считает, что переданные аргументы корректны.

Эту функцию нужно передать в `submit_form`:

```
lxml.html.submit_form(form, open_http=open_http)
```

---

Могу предложить альтернативное и более удобное решение, с использованием библиотеки [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

Для того, чтобы отправить ваши данные (в этом случае), нужно использовать POST запрос, в котором уже указать логин и пароль.

Посмотреть, какие данные требуется передать POST-запросом, можно, например, через средства разработчика браузера, вручную залогинившись.

Сейчас контакт, например, передаёт следующие параметры этим POST-запросом:

```
act: login
role: al_frame
expire: 
captcha_sid: 
captcha_key: 
_origin: http://vk.com
ip_h: <ip_h>
email: <email>
pass: <pass>
```

Конкретные значения смотрите самостоятельно, в вашем случае они могут отличаться.

Заметьте также, что запрос на авторизацию отправляется уже на другой адрес: `https://login.vk.com/?act=login`

---

В случае использования библиотеки requests, код будет иметь примерно такой вид:

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as session:
    login_url = 'https://login.vk.com/?act=login'

    login_data = {
        'act': 'login',
        'role': 'al_frame',
        'expire': '',
        'captcha_sid': '',
        'captcha_key': '',
        '_origin': 'http://vk.com',
        'ip_h': '<ip_h>',
        'email': '<email>',
        'pass': '<pass>'
    }

    headers = {
        'referer': 'http://vk.com/'
    }

    session.post(login_url, data=login_data, headers=headers)
    page = session.get('https://vk.com/settings')
    print(page.content)
```

---

Также, возможно, стоит посмотреть в сторону vk API.

Comment: А может Вы напишите статью? Достаточно серьезные у Вас знания по этому вопросу!

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev я пытался повторить пример из документации (http://lxml.de/api/lxml.html-module.html#submit_form) и (http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#forms), но тогда получаю ошибку о том что: _POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str._ . Неужели данные внесенные в форму нужно еще и перекодировать?

Comment: Спасибо за библиотеку обязательно попробую

Comment: @user179608 Да, эта ошибка воспроизвелась, и не очень понятно, почему она возникает, притом что все строки, с которыми происходит взаимодействие передавал, как байтовые. Если есть желание, вы можете использовать Python 2, в нём такой ошибки не возникает.

Comment: @user179608 Выяснилось, что это баг реализации библиотеки lxml для Python 3. Внёс пояснение в начало ответа.